# Why we write Bearer in front of the token in the authorization header?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

When I have for example a post method - login, I get back the signed JSON web token. I watched some tutorials on youtube and there, when they check if the user is authorized, they send the JWT in the authorization header like:

> Bearer -token-

My question is: why they do that, when the same thing is working if we send only the token in the authorization header, without the "Bearer" in front of the token?

Comment: see also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it's in the relevant standards documents. The general scheme is that you first state the type of token ("Bearer" in this case) and then the token itself. There are other authentication schemes too and they use different type keywords (like "Basic" or "Digest"). If you control the web server and parse the headers yourself then, sure, you can use whatever syntax you like. You can even invent your own header, nobody's stopping you. But having it comply to a unified standard makes it a little easier down the road when  you need to integrate with other systems. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the perfect answer

Comment: The standard is described in the RFC6750: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750